# The number of automorphisms of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $M$ be a finite field and $|M| = p^s$, where $p$ is prime and $s \in \mathbb N$. Prove that the number of different isomorphisms field $M$ to $M$ equal to $s$ and this isomorphisms form a cyclic group under composition of isomorphisms.

We know that the multiplicative group of finite field is cyclic and all cyclic groups the same order are isomorphic. Because of this if I do not mistake the number of different isomorphisms $M^{\times}$ to $M^{\times}$ equal to the number of primitive elements in $M^{\times}$. And it is equal to $\phi(p^s - 1)$ where $\phi(n)$ - Euler function. But we should consider not only $M^{\times}$ but also the addition and I do not know what to do with it and how to connect it with the multiplicative group.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: As you noted, an automorphism must be in particular an automorphism of the multiplicative group. These have a certain shape, so check which ones respect the addition.

Comment: The automorphism group is always cyclic, generated by the Frobenius automorphism $x\to x^p$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can you explain about what shape do you say? I have no idea. I know that the multiplicative group is cyclic and abelian, no more.

Comment: Have you looked in any books that discuss finite fields or searched on the internet for "automorphism finite field"?

Comment: @Jihad why it is always cyclic, proof or some support for this please

Answer (score 2):

To make the question answered I copied for you the relevant paragraph (see pages [208](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOPRx.png), [209](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQeGY.png), [210](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgzTK.png), [211](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA7nY.png)) of a Russian translation of “Algebra” by Serge Lang.  Theorem 12 at p. 211 answers your question.

Comment: for any finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, the group $Aut( \mathbb{F}_{p^n})=G( \mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_{p})\cong Z_n$ am I correct. I don't know russian.

Comment: @sabeelmsk yes it is correct. You may see any stander algebra book.